# Adding values to rows, retrieving them and splitting them

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I have a MySQL database with column 'apps_owned'. Everytime a user buys an app, I want their row to have the AppID added to it. For example,

```
apps_owned = 1, 4, 75 etc.
```

How would I do this?

Next, I need to split these up into individual numbers in C#. I don't know how I would remove the comma's to get a whole number. Is there any way of doing this. I know how to get the numbers from the database, I just don't know how to add to them or split them. Is there any easier way to do this?

Comment: Read a tutorial about database normalization. You should use more then one table to properly design this relationship between Apps and Users.

Comment: PLEASE do not put a comma separate list of values.......PLEASE, I'm beggin'.

Comment: The easier way to do it is not to do it that way at all.  You should not concatenate information together if you need to query on it later.

Comment: @nvoigt So have one table per user???

Answer (score 0):

Let the DB do the work, have a table represent a users apps.  Then you could simply count, add, delete...

Answer (score 0):

To Split you can do something like:

```
var result = apps_owned.Split(' ').Select(x => int.Parse(x.ToString.Replace(",", ""))).ToArray<int>();
```